# Suffix to prefix and prefix to suffix in R

Tags: r, regex, string, prefix, suffix

I have a string.

```
String <- "like_a_butterfly_sting_like_a_bee_Float"
```

I can make the first prefix become the last suffix by pivoting on the first underscore.

```
gsub("^([^_]*)_(.*)$", "\\2_\\1",String)
```

How can I make the final suffix become the first prefix by pivoting on the last underscore?

```
Desired result: "Float_like_a_butterfly_sting_like_a_bee"
```

Comment: Use `^(.*)_([^_]*)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may swap the patterns in the first and second capturing group:

```
sub("^(.*)_([^_]*)$", "\\2_\\1",String)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hNRwwd/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `_` - a `_` char
- `([^_]*)` - Capturing group 2: zero or more chars other than `_`
- `$` - end of string